# AD and BE are the altitudes of the triangle ABC with orthocentre H,which lies in the interior of the triangle.If BH=AC,Find angle B

Tags: geometry

[image]After forming some equations we get angle DAC=EBC .After this I hit a dead end but I think this would require cosine law or some other trignometric relation.Please help  (HAVE BEEN WORKING ON THIS FOR A LONG TIME)

Comment: Maybe provide a picture to reason about?

Comment: i am new to this site so how do you do that?

Comment: You may use the geogebra app

Comment: i made a figure on paint

Comment: MS paint is not easy to work with so forgive the diagram

Comment: Are you familiar with trigonometry?

Comment: why did you ask

Comment: and yes i am sort of

Comment: $BH=\frac{BD}{\sin C}=\frac{AB\cos B}{\sin C}=\frac{CA\cos B}{\sin B}\implies \tan B=1\implies B=45^\circ$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\angle HBD = \angle CAD$ and $BH=AC$, the two right triangles $\triangle BHD$ and $\triangle ACD$ are congruent. Thus $HD = CD$, or $\angle HCD=45^\circ$. Now $CH\perp AB$, so $\angle B + \angle HCD = 90^\circ$ and we have $\angle B = 45^\circ$.

Comment: How ∠HBD = ∠CAD ??

Comment: They are both equal to $90^\circ - \angle C$ because $BH \perp AC$ and $AH \perp BC$.